# Why is my parser keep looping the print statemnt when it job should end?

Tags: python, loops

I am making a simple programming language WMC, and I am making an 'END()' command but whenever I use it when using the 'Display' command it just displays the name of the command

```
if Command[P] == "Display" and Running == "":
    Running = "Display"
elif Running == "Display":
    print(Command[P])
elif Command[P] == "END()":
    if Running != "":
        Running = ""
```

and I do not know why.

I tried moving where the if statement is but there is no luck, and while not new to python, I am new to arrays and making Commands in said 'arrays'.
Here is my source code:

```
Loop = 1

Command = []

P = -1

Running = ""

while Loop == 1:
    P += 1 
    In = input()
    if In == " ":
        continue
    else:
        Command.append(In)
    if Command[P] == "Display" and Running == "":
        Running = "Display"
    elif Running == "Display":
        print(Command[P])
    elif Command[P] == "END()":
        if Running != "":
            Running = ""
        elif Running == "":
            print("CLOSING...")
            exit()
```

I expected the 'END()' command to take me out of the display loop, but it only displays "END()" and carries on as if nothing was done, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to place the Closing on top and using a break to get out of the loop. Hope this works.

```
while Loop == 1:
    P += 1 
    In = input("?")
    if In == " ":
        continue
    else:
        Command.append(In)
    if Command[P] == "END()":
        print("CLOSING...")
        break
    elif Command[P] == "Display" and Running == "":
        Running = "Display"
    elif Running == "Display":
        print(Command[P])
```

Comment: sadly it does not, sorry. The program will not open now, also it will jump out of the loop even if I use the "END()" command with the "Display" command.

Answer (score 1):

If you entered "Display" then Running is assigned to "Display". There is no way for Running to be assigned to anything else and thereafter everything command you put in will simply print due to:

```
elif Running == "Display":
    print(Command[P])
```